# JPA Repositories object identity

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, eclipselink, object-identity

When loading an entity twice using `findOne()` two different objects with the same values are returned.

I would have expected that an object identity is preserved using an  [Identity map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_map_pattern).

Is there any reason why this is not the case or is there an way to influence that?

Btw, I'm using Spring JPA repositiories with eclipselink, but I have seen the same with hibernate.

Comment: Please post code. If you load the same object twice in the same session you should get the same instance, otherwise something is wrong.

Comment: you have to use the same EntityManager context, and depending on the setup, you might need to be in a transaction or the container might not be using the same EntityManager underneath each call.